# Unable to run spring-boot-test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I am new to Spring-boot.

We are trying to practice spring-boot-test by adding the following Java class in this [Spring guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) for testing purpose.
However, it turns out that we are not able to trigger this Java class. In other words, there is no any test result showing up in the our eclipse console.
Could someone suggest us where we do wrong?

Thanks!

**GreetingControllerTest.java**

```
package hello;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class GreetingControllerTest {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 

    @Test
    public void testGreeting() {

        System.out.println("Where is my TEST?????!!!!!!");
        String url = "http://localhost:8080/greeting";
        assertNotNull(restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to "trigger" it?

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding. What we meant is that the entire spring-framework simply doesn't run GreetingControllerTest.java. How do we tell Spring-framework to run our test class??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Framework does not run (*trigger*) tests. Rather, a testing framework like JUnit or TestNG runs tests.

Your code appears to be fine. So, assuming that the example you supplied compiles (i.e., has the correct package imports) and assuming that the `@Test` annotation you have declared is `@org.junit.Test`, then you simply need to *run* the test as a JUnit test.

Your IDE (e.g., Eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans) and build framework (e.g., Maven, Ant, Gradle) should provide support for running JUnit tests.

Regards,

Sam